# How to Initialize Letter Guess Prompt Error in Hangman (Python)

Tags: python

I'm writing a hangman code, and am having trouble with setting an error for an invalid letter guess (ie. the guess should be between a-z, no numbers or multiple letter strings). This may be a fairly simple solution, but I am having trouble formalizing the code. Here is how I implemented the code:

```
while ((count < 6) and win):
   guess = input("Please enter the letter you guess: ")
   if guess:
      try:
         guess = guess.lower()
         lettersCorrect += 1
      if (guess not in letterList): #SYNTAX ERROR
         print ("You need to input a single alphabetic character!")
         continue
```

I noted where I am getting the syntax error. letterList is a list I created containing all acceptable letters (a-z). Is my coding off, or is there an easier way to say, "if not in letterList".

Thanks.

Comment: You have it correct, you just forgot and `except` block.  But it is really superfluous to include a try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `try` block is pointless. Also, instead of `letterList`, you can use `string.lowercase`

```
import string

while count < 6 and win:
   guess = input("Please enter the letter you guess: ")
   if guess:
      guess = guess.lower()
      if guess not in string.lowercase:
         print("You need to input a single alphabetic character!")
         continue
      lettersCorrect += 1
```

Comment: or may be just use `if guess.isalpha()`.